# How can I get a blinking cursor in KDE Konsole?

Tags: terminal, cursor, flash

I have switched to Emacs as my editor and when using multiple windows in the terminal I want the cursor to flash in the current window.

I have run the `(blink-cursor-mode t)` command and nothing happens. I have also tried a few commands to get the cursor to flash in the terminal and nothing happens.

Comment: (A note: `blink-cursor-mode` does not apply to emacs within a terminal: "This command is effective only on graphical frames. On text-only terminals, cursor blinking is controlled by the terminal." -- from `C-h f blink-cursor-mode`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a konsole setting: Settings → Edit Current Profile… → Advanced, checkbox "Blinking cursor". I had to exit and restart konsole before it took effect here.

Answer (score 1):

In KDE plasma 5.18.4, the checkbox has been removed from the Edit Current Profile  → Advanced dialogue box.  It's moved to Appearance, Cursor tab. Or, one can add

```
BlinkingCursorEnabled=true
```

to the [Terminal Features] section of the .profile file in ~.local/share/konsole.